# DB2 load ( client in remote | file in the db2 server )

Tags: db2

I'm using db2 client in windows to connect to Linux DB2 server.

I'm trying to upload data using my client but the data is in the /tmp/  directory in the host server.

If I use `LOAD FROM "/tmp/file.txt" OF ..` it fails  with message `QL2036N  The path for the file, named pipe, or device "/tmp/file.txt" is not valid.`

It is possible doing thins without db2 connect from the server itself ?

regards

Comment: thank you !!!  I've just change the chmod of file.txt to 777 and is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment thread:  the solution was to ensure that the Db2-instance owner has read access to the file on the server.

When you use `load from` then the specified file must reside on the Db2-server, and the Db2-instance owner (e.g. db2inst1) on the server must have read access to the file. DOUBLE CHECK the permissions/ownerships. If the file is on your workstation use `load client from`.